# Highcharts pie rendering in conflict with legend

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have an example of a Highcharts pie with a top positioned legend.

```
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        verticalAlign: 'top'
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wt4rqudh/1/

There is an addSeries button in the demo which adds an inner pie chart. Because this adds more rows to the legend, the pie rendered is pushed down resulting in an incorrect behaviour.

Does anyone know how to fix this? The legend position must remain the same.

Comment: What is the desired behavior? What do you want to happen to the legend?

Comment: @Ondkloss As I mentioned above the new pie being rendered is pushed down (is not aligned with the previous pie due to the legend.) that is what I want to fix

Comment: So you still want the new legend items to appear as they do now? Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method that makes this look somewhat smooth is:

1. Doing the `chart.addSeries`, but without redrawing
2. Doing an `update` on the original series, still not redrawing
3. Do a `chart.redraw()` to position both series

In code this looks something like this:

```
chart.addSeries({
    // Series attributes ...
}, false);
chart.series[0].update(null, false);
chart.redraw();
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wt4rqudh/2/) of how it looks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're adding series, old one never get removed, so you basically get multiple pie charts on one chart.

Before you add new series you must remove old one:

```
 $('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].remove();
    chart.addSeries({
        size: '70%',
        innerSize: '50%',
        data: []
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7sopburu/.

Comment: I want both series that is not a mistake. One inside the other.